# How to insert unicode to file

Tags: centos, terminal, unicode

I'm using [fish-shell](http://fishshell.com/) on CentOS8.

I  would like to insert the following to file.

```
function fish_title
    echo " AmericaN "
end
```

But upon trying to paste it into the file,
I see the following:

```
function fish_title
    echo " AmericaN "
end
```

[image]

Even via `cat` command, I am still unable to see it.

Here's the output of `locale` and `$TERM`

```
❯ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

```
❯ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

I'm using [Windows New Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) to access my `CentOS` server, and I'm pasting to the file using <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT+INSERT</kbd> or `mouse` right-click

The editor is `nano`

Comment: How exactly are you "pasting it into the file"?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm pasting to the file using `CTRL+V` or  `SHIFT+INSERT`

Comment: @JeffSchaller also using `mouse` right-click

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Yes but what application?  vim?  atom? emacs? ed?

Comment: @Jesse_b `nano`

Comment: It is probably your terminal or font. Can you test by viewing in another terminal?

Comment: Really, then, this question is about the behaviour of two Windows programs, running on Windows; Windows New Terminal and the Windows OpenSSH client.

Comment: @JdeBP even if i did run `ssh.exe` directly. it's will be the same. because `ssh.exe` relay on `cmd` or `PowerShell`. Anyway I've verified that `OpenSSH` version 7 is actually not supporting sending `Unicode`. therefore, version 8 which is beta already fixed that behavior .

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor i tried with Putty. and got the same result.

Comment: Can you add a link to where you read about version 8 adding unicode support?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/4280#issuecomment-575694458

Comment: Let me put it another way:  You are having problems copying and pasting non-SBCS text using the Windows clipboard, into a Windows program, that is a terminal emulator talking to another Windows program, via a Windows console object, on Windows; and this is the _Unix and Linux StackExchange_.

Comment: @JdeBP alright , got it

Comment: @JdeBP Flag for migration, if you think it needs it, but stop being mean.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη that link does not cite references either. ssh should not be doing this. It should pass the bytes without interpretation. However I would not be surprised if some one put the code in to get it to work on MS-Windows. It seems like the wrong layer to me. But when you have poor architecture, you just do a hack to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I managed to fix the issue by asking the [developers](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/4280#issuecomment-575694458) of `Windows New Terminal` about why I'm unable to paste `Unicode` over `SSH` connection.

And i got the following response:

```
The version of OpenSSH-Win32 that’s available today doesn’t support receiving Unicode. That has been fixed pending release!
```

So I've just wrote it to online editor and downloaded it via `wget`

```
wget https://bpaste.net/raw/OXEQ -O test
```

and now it's works.

```
❯ cat test
function fish_title
    echo " AmericaN "
end⏎
```

Comment: This is an issue with Windows New Terminal itself? I've just tried it under Cygwin (`mintty.exe`) and had no issues.

Comment: @roaima it's not about `Windows New Terminal`. actually it's about `OpenSSH` current version.

Comment: I wonder what Cygwin's using for its SSH implementation then. Works fine there remotely, too.

Comment: @roaima you are lucky though. they are using the latest beta version which actually supporting `Unicode` paste ! https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/openssh.html

Comment: On my end it's version 7. but yours is version 8 :)

Comment: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/tag/v8.1.0.0p1-Beta

Comment: That is real weird as ssh should just pass bytes. It should not be concerned with characters.

Comment: The locus of the problem is not the SSH session, but the communications between the two Windows programs.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tired this in konsole( the KDE terminal). It showed the flames as a box (indicating no character in the font). I then went to the font configuration for the terminal, almost all fonts show a box, a space, or a hexcode character.

One font (that had the name emoji in the name) showed the flames.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I tried it with printf and it worked:
Try: `printf  >> file.txt`

You could also do an alias:

`# $1 = File, $2 = Emoji 
 alias addEmoji="printf $2 >> $1"`

Mind I switched the arguments around because I had some issues displaying after I pasted the Emoji. 
If you want to play around with Unicode some more, I recommend this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/602924/12546645